# Access - Application Echo not working

Tags: ms-access-2010

I want to stop flickering of my form when VBA code is executed, but Application Echo is not working.

1. I have this code in Combobox_After_Update event :

   Private Sub Combo11_AfterUpdate()

   ```
   'Stop flickering
   Application.Echo False

   On Error Resume Next

     'If User deletes Combo Item, then delete record
     If IsNull(Combo11) Then
     DoCmd.SetWarnings False
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
     End If

    'Call code for re-positioning controls on form
    Call MovingAllControls

   'Close and reopen form
   Call ReOpen

   Application.Echo True

   End Sub
   ```
2. Called procedure (which is probably cause of flickering):

Sub MovingAllControls

```
'Refresh
DoCmd.Requery

Const MaxRecs As Integer = 10
Dim NumRecs As Integer

 On Error Resume Next

'find last record in subform and then expand Detail section according to number 'of records

With Forms![MyForm]![MySubform].Form
.Recordset.MoveLast
NumRecs = .RecordsetClone.RecordCount
If NumRecs > MaxRecs Then NumRecs = MaxRecs
.InsideHeight = NumRecs * .Section(0).Height + 350

End With

'Moving all controls under subform - in this example only one, but in reality I 'have plenty controls to move on form

Forms![MyForm]![FieldName].Top = Forms![MyForm]![Myubform].Top + Forms![MyForm]![MySubform].Form.InsideHeight + 1100

End Sub
```

3. Another procedure that is called from Combobox_After_Update event:

   Sub ReOpen()

   ```
   'I reopen form, because this is only way my subform controls moves as they 'should - dynamically

   DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyForm"
   DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"

   End Sub
   ```

I also tried to to see what error is producing in After_Update_event, and I get error "424 - object required", but my code excecutes, only problem is flickering of controls. Any other way to stop flickering, or what is wrong with my code ?

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `Application.Echo False`, try the `Form.Painting` method:

```
' code under form
Me.Painting = False

' do actions that cause flicker

Me.Painting = True
Me.Repaint
```

Also, looking at your code here:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyForm"
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
```

I would say this is bad practice:

- This can cause performance problems for even moderately large record sets.
- If you use events like `Form_Open` or `Form_Close`, this can cause bugs by re-running code that was intended to only run once, when the form was first opened.

There is always a way in Access to get the results you want without closing/reopening the form.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but there is still something wrong with code. On first moving of subform control everything still flickers, but  then It stops ?!? Now that you say about Form_Open and Form_Close bugs I really believe that something is wrong there. My code actually re-positions all controls on Form_Load, I didn't post this here. And when this posted code is executed, I have to perform Form_Load again, this is the only way all controls refresh correctly. How else could I do refresh dynamically ?

Comment: **1)** Try the `Painting` code in the subform, parent form, or both. **2)** Move the control positioning code out of `Form_Load`, and into it's own subroutine, that you can call when you need to.

Comment: Sorry, I allready have control positioning code out of Form_Load, I just call It. Maybe calling this subroutine from Form_Current event would be better ?

Comment: It is worth trying `Form_Current`. Did you make any headway on the flicker?

Comment: No, no headway, flickering still appears, this is how I did It:                                    

On Error Resume Next

  'If User deletes Combo Item, then delete record
  If IsNull(Combo11) Then
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
  End If
Me.Painting = False
 'Call code for re-positioning controls on form
 Call MovingAllControls

'Close and reopen form
Call ReOpen

Me.Painting=True
Me.Repaint                                                                                         End Sub

Comment: OK, looking at your code: **1)** Comment out the `Call ReOpen` line. Reason: when the form re-opens, Painting is reset to True, and anything that happens after that can cause flicker. **2)** Try moving the `Me.Painting = False` above the `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`, maybe the flicker is happening around the `acCmdDeleteRecord` line.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but none of your suggestions removed flickering. I'v tried everything - removed ReOpen code, and moved Me.Painting code everywhere, even duplicated It on several lines, but flickering still appears. I believe that whole code is inconstistent, looks like I'll have to figure out a new solution....